# Object level cascading permission in Django

Tags: python, django, permissions, cascade

Projects such as Django-guardian and django-permissions enables you to have object level permissions. However, if two objects are related to each other by a parent-child relationship, is there any way for the child object to inherit permission from the parent object unless otherwise specified? For instance, a `subfolder` should inherit permission from `parent folder` unless a user explicitly assigns a different permission for the subfolder.

What's the best way to accomplish this using Django, in particular, the Django-guardian module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you check if a user has permissions on an object, and doesn't, then you can check if it has permission on its parent.

You might even want to make your own function, for example:

```
def your_has_perm(user, perm, obj):
    has = user.has_perm(perm, obj)

    if not has and hasattr(obj, 'parent'):
        return your_has_perm(user, perm, obj.parent)

    return has
```

This should traverse parents until it finds a permission for a parent or return False.

Comment: This will not work well. How could you know if permissions was generated automatically and you should change them if parents permissions changes?

Comment: Right, I didn't like it a lot, the answer was updated with a much simpler way. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Make sense. Where's the best place to put a method like this? Additionally, since recursive permission checking is done in code, how do you query the database for a list of all objects user has permission to?

Comment: "Where's the best place to put a method like this?" it doesn't matter. Personally I like to make a project_specific app where I put my project-specific snippets. "how do you query the database for a list of all objects user has permission to?" Use [get_objects_for_user](http://packages.python.org/django-guardian/api/guardian.shortcuts.html#get-objects-for-user)

Comment: the problem is that because the permission can now be inherited, the get_objects_for_user method no longer suffices because it does not take into account inherited permissions.

Comment: Then just do the same trick than for your_has_perm: make your_get_objects_for_user(), that adds object.children recursively for each object returned by get_objects_for_user()